# Create new mail addresses on mail server using PHP $_POST data

Tags: php, mail-server, email-address

We have a mail server and we want to create new mail addresses with user submitted details. Is it possible to do it with php?

Comment: No, it's completely impossible. Use F# or Fortran instead.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to do it with php?

yes.

However, you need to know how to operate this mail server, as there is no createNewMailAddres() finction in PHP yet.